# Add column with id in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Have a table in Oracle db such like this:

```
Word  Cnt
 A     20
 B     25
 C     23
 B     29
 D     31
```

What I trying to do - is to add an additional column with id of a word. But it is not a primary key it wont be unique because of repeating words. So the outcome I'm looking for is:

```
Word  Cnt   ID
 A     20   1
 B     25   2
 C     23   3
 B     29   2 
 D     31   4
```

How can I perform that in Oracle SQL?

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_alter_table_add_column_syntax_example.htm

Comment: I don't think the `alter table` is the difficult part here ;-)

Comment: Do you want to _permanently_ change the table structure or just get that column as port of a `SELECT` statement?

Comment: @ammoQ It's always hard to say in questions that do not contain a single line of actual code ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window function to calculate the ID:

```
select word, 
       cnt, 
       dense_rank() over (order by word) as id
from the_table;
```

You can update the table using the above, if you really need to persist that:

```
merge into the_table tg
using (
  select rowid as rid,
         dense_rank() over (order by word) as new_id
  from the_table
) t on (t.rid = tg.rowid)
when matched then update
   set id = t.new_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution requires a lot of nested subqueries, but it works...

```
alter table mytable add (id number(12));

update mytable
  set id = (select n from 
              (select word, rownum n from 
                 (select word from mytable group by word order by word)
              ) x where mytable.word = x.word
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is just to select

```
  select word,cnt,count(*) over(partition by word,count) as Id from table_name;
```